# Storing HTML tags including PHP script in the database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

i'm trying to store html tag that includes php script.
This is for the navigation menu, i'm trying to display only the menu for a particular user role.

I'm storing it this way

```
public function edit_module(){
    $id = $this->input->post('Module_ID', TRUE);
    $update = $this->db->update('ref_modules', array('Module_Name'=>$this->input->post('Module_Name', TRUE), 
                                                    'Module_Menu'=> htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('Module_Menu')),
                                                    'UpdatedBy'=>$this->session->userdata('user_id')), "Module_ID = '$id'");
    if($update){
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

For display

```
 <!--Menu-->
                <!--================================-->
                <div id="mainnav-menu-wrap">
                    <div class="nano">
                        <div class="nano-content">
                            <ul id="mainnav-menu" class="list-group">

                                <!--Category name-->
                                <li class="list-header">Navigation</li>

                                <?php if($this->data['menu']): ?>
                                    <?php foreach($this->data['menu'] as $row): ?>
                                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row->Module_Menu); ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- nano -->
                </div><!-- mainnav-menu-wrap -->
                <!--================================-->
                <!--End menu-->
```

When i view the source, its fine but when i click the link, special characters are showing.

```
http://localhost/folderName/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url(%27citizens%27);%20?%3E
```

Here's a sample value that i am inserting

```
<li class="<?php echo ($title == 'Citizens' ? 'active-link' : '');?>">
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('citizens'); ?>">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <span class="menu-title">
                                            <strong>Citizens</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
```

Any idea guys? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `urlencode`

Comment: No good, because the url is inside the html tags. I've edited the question and included the tags that i am inserting

Comment: why do you want to save this value in the database

Comment: Because i'm trying to make it manageable, for example i'm going to edit the name.

Comment: don't save it like this...make a use of if conditions

Comment: Yes, i did it that way. I was just trying to make it cms-like. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Inserting Html into database For Different user role is not the right way. You can use if Conditions To show your Menu for different User roles.